# ajax call stucks on beforsend function

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
    $(document).ready(function(){   


$('.gbutton').click(function(){

    text=$("#textid").val();

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url : "postquery.php",
        data: "text="+text,

        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#loading').show();
        }

        success: function(html)
        {

            $('#new_query_post').html(html);
        }



    });

});

        });
```

this code is working fine without beforeSend function but stops completely on adding beforeSend function..

Answer (score 1):

Missing `,` after `beforeSend`

```
beforeSend: function(){
    $('#loading').show();
},  /*
 ^  */
success: function(html){
    $('#new_query_post').html(html);
}
```